# grouping data without group by method in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have 1M row dataset. And inside of it, I have 50k unique `person_id`. The goal is to apply the DBSCAN algorithm individually to these 50k unique `person_id`. So basically I need to create clusters for each `person_id`. At the moment I'm doing similar to this:

```
def DBSCAN(x):
    cluster = DBSCAN(eps=0.5, min_samples=3).fit(x)
    cluster_labels = cluster.labels_
    return cluster_labels

grouped = df_sample.groupby(["person_id"])
grouped.apply(lambda x: DBSCAN(x))
```

But that's means is running the function fifty thousand times. Because clustering must be applied individually to each `person_id`.

I want to able to run the code only one time for each unique `person_id` instead of running 50k times.  Is there any way to create a lookup without running the function over and over again for each `person_id`?

It doesn't have to be the only python, also I'm able to SQL, pyspark, etc. I need a solution to escape from this loop.

Comment: Try to implement vectorization in your function and call

Comment: pls, correct me if I'm wrong but vectorization makes the code faster only. There is no plus for looping side, the function will ve run again 50k times. If you think there is one more usage to avoid from `group by` , can you pls explain pls? @Teja

Comment: " I have 50k unique person_id" , "I want to able to run the code only one time for each unique person_id instead of running 50k times." ??

Comment: When you apply groupby for person_id , you run the function total count of groups times. In my case I have 50k unique person_id , that’s mean is 50k groups , that’s mean is function will be run 50k times. So I wanted to say I wish I could run the code only one time instead of 50k times . I mean, I want to have a look up which must run for each individually itself of person_id. Is that clear enough? @kubatucka

Comment: @emily.mi sorry but since you have 50K unique groups and you want to apply a function for those groups, it will be called 50K times in one way or the other. To simplify what you want to do or what you are looking for, it's vectorization so that your code will be much faster and cleaner.

Comment: definitely agree you. after your comment I made a search about vectorisation of groupby. however I only found answer of basic function call such as sum() , count() etc. could you help me implementation of this kind of functional call? @Teja

Comment: Hey! Take a look a this benchmark of different clustering implementations: https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/performance_and_scalability.html . It might help with improving the performance of the clustering. Since the number of points per person is ~20, I'm not sure how much it could be improved.As for the grouby itself, you could try to do it yourself and see if it improves. Here are 2 slightly different ways of doing it yourself: http://esantorella.com/2016/06/16/groupby/   https://medium.com/deeplearningmadeeasy/how-to-speed-up-pandas-groupby-acd372f3d7c7

Comment: Also since the clustering functions are independant you could paralelize the clusterings. You could use multiprocessing to do it explicitly or use another library such as dask to do it for you.